# Are advanced VHDL configurations ever used in real life?

Tags: vhdl

VHDL configurations can be used to bind components to entities with a different name, and even with completely different ports. [[see this article for more info]](http://www.sigasi.com/content/advanced-vhdl-configurations-tying-component-unrelated-entity)

```
  configuration c2 of testbench is
    for str
        for dut_inst : dut
            use entity work.unrelated(rtl)
                port map(
                    port1 => a,
                    port2 => b,
                    port3 => c,
                    port4 => "unused"
                );
        end for;
    end for;
  end configuration c2;
```

Have any of you ever seen this happen in a commercial project project? What was the purpose for dropping in a seemingly unrelated entity? Why did they not just change the instantiation code?

I can make up hypothetical situations, but I'm interested in a real-life use case.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - I am also very interested. In my experience I have never seen this used myself and have worked in large code bases targeting multiple FPGA boards/systems.

Comment: Same for me. VHDL seems to have a couple of language elements that make it feel very old and specified for a different and smaller userbase than today's FPGA engineers. Sensitivity lists, configurations, mandatory labels, lack of the equivalent of a C preprocessor, insisting that the last element in a list must not have a trailing coma, or distinguishing between std_logic and bool when ever developer will assume '1'=true and name the signal accordingly. The basic concepts are fine, but someone needs to redesign the language from scratch.

Comment: @maxy: Some of those I'll agree with, and some not. Sensitivity lists are a relic from when compilers/sims weren't as capable, so I'll give you that. Trailing commas, yeah okay, but I'm not losing sleep over it. Configurations are powerful and useful (although the example above seems unnecessary). I don't want a preprocessor. Have you seen the horrific things that people do with it? Generics get you 90% there, but enforce structure. std_logic vs bool is an artefact of having a rigidly typed language, and rigid typing is a good thing for RTL IMHO. Labels...why wouldn't you label something? :-)

Comment: verilog has similar constructs, also called configurations. I've never seen them used either.

Answer (score 5):

Never seen the port bindings change, but I have seen it used to bind in different versions of components with the same port map. Some examples I've seen:

- Binding in empty versions when building large system level simulations. Part of the design is replaced by versions that don't do anything to keep the memory footprint down when testing other parts of the design.
- Similar, but when testing the bus infrastructure of a design, bind in simple units that respond in "wild'n'wacky" ways.
- Different versions of a particular block which have different design compromises. e.g. One large and fast version, one small but slow. Can then be swapped out depending on what's needed when the system comes together or for a particular application.

None of these need the features you're talking about though. The only thing I can think of that using a different component might be useful for is if you've got something like multiple RAM library vendors, and need to swap between them regularly. Even then it's unlikely you're going to be able to do a one-for-one port mapping. There's always a power-down pin that needs inverting or something.

Comment: I'd add (1) swapping behavioural models for RTL models as a large project progresses, and (2) using the configuration to select different versions of a simulation. This is all commonplace in big projects. I'd also add that you only need to talk to a Verilogger to find out how painful it is to be allowed only one name when that name exists as different components in different libraries. Configs are, IMO, fundamental to VHDL.

Answer (score 3):

No, I've never seen that in the wild.

I guess the reason is that most people (myself included) don't even know that such things are possible with configurations.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this kind of configuration a few times. I try to avoid it, but it is sometimes useful for whitebox testing.

Suppose I have a very large entity+architecture FooMachine, and I wish to write a series of whitebox unit tests referring to signals inside FooMachine. Ideally, FooMachine would be split into several components and I would write black-box tests on these, but I have inherited some truly massive architectures where I could not from an economic standpoint justify the time required to refactor when only minor changes were required. What I will do is define a component in `FooMachine`

```
component Dummy is
end component Dummy;
```

and an instance

```
dummy_g : Dummy;
```

Then, in a unit test of signal `x` in `FooMachine`, I will write an entity+architecture

```
entity TestDummy is
    port (
        x : in std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture Arch of TestDummy is
    ...
end Arch;
```

and a configuration

```
configuration conf of ... is
...
    for all : FooMachine
        ...
        for all : Dummy
            use entity work.TestDummy(Arch)
                port map (x => x);
        end for;
    end for;
...
end configuration;
```

And then I can write my assertions in `TestDummy`.

Again, this is not how I prefer to write my unit tests, but there have been times when this was the best solution to an unfortunate problem.

Comment: great answer, not many people understand the implications and usefulness of this